# JS: How to determine if font have glyph for character?

Tags: javascript

How to determine if font have glyph for character?

Is this even possible?

```
var a = glyph_exist('0x00A1')
console.log(a)

true or false
```

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one](http://s.tk/onhold).

Answer (score 3):

**[Fontkit](https://github.com/devongovett/fontkit)** appears to support this use case:

> Fontkit is an advanced font engine for Node and the browser, used by PDFKit. It supports many font formats, advanced glyph substitution and layout features, glyph path extraction, color emoji glyphs, font subsetting, and more.
>
> [...]
>
> **`font.hasGlyphForCodePoint(codePoint)`**
>
> Returns whether there is glyph in the font for the given unicode code point.